# Prevent React component from resetting the data when a dialog open

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out on how to prevent my component variables from being reset when I open a dialog. I have an API call in one the component where I fetch the data and display the data in the component, but whenever I try to open the dialog, API call happens and the component variables are being reset everytime the dialog is opened and closed.

```
const UserContent = props => {
   const [key, setKey] = useState();
   const [data, setData] = useState();

   const getData = async () => {
      if (!key) {
         return;
      }
      // fetches data with respect to key
      setData(values);
   };

   const getKey = async () => {
      // API call to fetch the key
      setKey(key);
   };

   useAsync(getKey, [!key]);
   useAsync(getData, [key]);

   return (
     // UI template to display the data with loader
   );
};

export default UserContent;
```

I don't want to make API fetch calls and reset key & data values whenever the dialog is opened or closed. I hope someone helps me to figure out the solution.

I'm new to React and I started my React journey just 2 weeks back. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple solution is don't fetch data in `UserContent` instead fetch the data inside the parent component of `UserContent` and pass the data to `UserContent` as props.

Comment: Also check this, how to pass props to child - https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html